# Ubuntu python subprocess permision denied

Tags: python, nginx, flask, subprocess, gunicorn

У меня есть приложение в связке nginx+gunicorn+flask.
в определённый момент приложение создаёт файл bash скрипта, наполняет его, а потом отдельно запускает (такой вот костыль для выполнения баш скриптов из пайтона, лучше не придумал)

```
def addClientToVPN(clientName=str, clientIp=str, clientPublicKey=str):
    cmd = f'sudo wg set wg0 peer {clientPublicKey} allowed-ips {clientIp}/32'
    with open(f'/root/VPNcon/tmpScripts/{clientName}tmpScript.sh', 'w') as f:
        f.write(f'#!/bin/bash\nexport PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"\n{cmd}')
    try:
        stdout = subprocess.check_output(f'/root/VPNcon/tmpScripts/{clientName}tmpScript.sh', shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT).decode('utf-8')
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        raise RuntimeError("command '{}' return with error (code {}): {}".format(e.cmd, e.returncode, e.output))

    return stdout
```

Так вот, в момент создания файла ( `with open('...', 'w')`), ему выдаются права `-rw-r--r--`, от чего `subprocess.check_output(...)` выдаёт ошибку `Permission denied`

`chmod` помогает, но на новые файлы права не распространяются.
Как исправить?

Comment: Ну, просто делайте chmod после создания файла да и всё?

Comment: Смысле ручками прописывать? Это не удобно, предполагается, что это временный файл, который создаётся, выполняется и удаляется. И в теории, таких файлов может быть неограниченное кол-во в день, так что на каждый chmod'ом не напасёшься

Comment: Хотелось бы, чтобы файл сразу создавался с нужными правами.

Comment: Вы можете использовать [os.fchmod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fchmod) и(или) [os.chmod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chmod) во время записи скрипта для изменения его прав.

Comment: Это помогло, спасибо! Напишите тогда полноценным ответом, если никто ничего лучше не предложит, то помечу как лучший

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать [os.stat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat) для получения уже имеющихся прав, и [os.chmod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chmod) для изменения их у созданного sh файла.

```py
import os
import subprocess
import stat


def addClientToVPN(clientName=str, clientIp=str, clientPublicKey=str):
    cmd = f'sudo wg set wg0 peer {clientPublicKey} allowed-ips {clientIp}/32'
    path = f'/root/VPNcon/tmpScripts/{clientName}tmpScript.sh'
    with open(path, 'w') as f:
        f.write(f'#!/bin/bash\nexport PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"\n{cmd}')
    # Добавляем execute к уже имеющимся правам
    permissions = os.stat(path).st_mode \
        | stat.S_IXUSR | stat.S_IXGRP | stat.S_IXOTH
    os.chmod(path, permissions)  # И изменяем их у файла

    ...  # уже имеющийся код, который я не изменил
```